# How to order @Before methods

Tags: scala, junit, junit4

I have a trait that adds a couple of tests and before blocks. The @Before blocks of the concrete instance are run before the ones in the trait. Oops, this means I can't truncate database tables then insert fixtures:

```
trait DatabaseTest {
  @Before
  def truncate() {
    // "TRUNCATE %s".format(tableName)
  }

  def tableName
}

class PersonasTest extends DatabaseTest {
  @Before
  def addPersona() {
    // "INSERT INTO %s VALUES (...)".format(tableName)
  }


  @Test
  def testRejectsInsertWhenAlreadyInTable() {
    // "INSERT INTO %s VALUES (...)".format(tableName)
  }

  def tableName = "personas"
}
```

`testRejectsInsertWhenAlreadyInTable` will always succeed because the execution order will be:

- `addPersona`
- `truncate`
- `testRejectsInsertWhenAlreadyInTable`

What would be the proper way of ordering the @Before blocks without imposing too many constraints on the subclasses? I could always declare `truncate` in the trait, then have an @Before method in the subclass, but then I have to remember to make all my subclasses call that truncate method.

Using JUnit 4.10 on Scala 2.9.0.1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct way of doing this is to use `@Rule`, extend `@ExternalResource` for before and after type behaviour (in Java syntax):

```
@Rule
public ExternalResource resource= new ExternalResource() {
        @Override
        protected void before() throws Throwable {
                myServer.connect();
        };

        @Override
        protected void after() {
                myServer.disconnect();
        };
};
```

You can chain and order multiple `@Rule`s together in order by using the `@RuleChain` (introduced in 4.10), again in java syntax:

```
@Rule
public TestRule chain= RuleChain
                       .outerRule(new LoggingRule("outer rule")
                       .around(new LoggingRule("middle rule")
                       .around(new LoggingRule("inner rule");
```

There is a caveat. You can't specify a public field in scala (public field's are wrapped with accessor methods, and the fields themselves become private). JUnit checks that the @Rule applies to a public field. The fix to change the JUnit code so that you can apply @Rule to methods as well as fields.

This has been fixed (by me), and has been merged into master, but unfortunately, it's not yet released: it will be part of 4.11. So you have two options: use the 4.11-SNAPSHOT, or download the 4.10 release and apply the [patch for @Rule](https://github.com/KentBeck/junit/commit/1660ebdf1ebc316747a1c3f29c03f616125a9dc7).

The scala code could look something like:

```
trait DatabaseTest {
    def truncate(): TestRule = {
        new ExternalResource() {
            override def before() = {
                // "TRUNCATE %s".format(tableName)
            }
        }
    }

    def extra(): TestRule = {
        // return a no-op rule
    }

    @Rule def testRule() = new RuleChain(truncate(), extra())
    def tableName
}

class PersonasTest extends DatabaseTest {
  def extra(): TestRule {
        new ExternalResource() {
            override def before() = {
                // "INSERT INTO %s VALUES (...)".format(tableName)
            }
        }
  }

  @Test
  def testRejectsInsertWhenAlreadyInTable() {
    // "INSERT INTO %s VALUES (...)".format(tableName)
  }

  def tableName = "personas"
}
```

Comment: Where is the JUnit snapshot repo? According to build.xml https://github.com/KentBeck/junit/blob/master/build.xml#L306, I should find it at https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots but only 4.9.1 is there.

Comment: I think that there has been a mistake. The nightly build seems to be the 4.9.1 rather than 4.11-SNAPSHOT. I've emailed the maintainer.

Comment: 4.9.1-SNAPSHOT does not contain ChainRule, thus it's probably 4.9.1 rather than 4.11. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Sorry, yes, I'm certain it's building 4.9.1. It's configuration problem on the integration server.

Answer (score 0):

How about :

```
abstract class DatabaseTest {

  // "TRUNCATE %s".format(tableName)

  def tableName
}

class PersonasTest extends DatabaseTest {
  @Before
  def addPersona() {
    // "INSERT INTO %s VALUES (...)".format(tableName)
  }

  @Test
  def testRejectsInsertWhenAlreadyInTable() {
    // "INSERT INTO %s VALUES (...)".format(tableName)
  }

  def tableName = "personas"
}
```

After all, `PersonasTest` **is-a** `DatabaseTest`.